# Radio button and display

Tags: c#, mysql, textbox, radio-button, messagebox

I have a `ListBox` , `Button` and `RadioButton`. When I click a `button`, different kind of drink will list out on the `ListBox`.

I want let user select drinks size and show out the price. When user check `large radio button` large size price will show out. The price was link with the database.

The problem is when I select the radio button, the price won't show until I click the drinks button again. I want the price show when then radio button was checked.

Here is my coding

```
private void signatureMilkTeaButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=000";
    string Query = "select* from database.drinks where drinks_Type ='M';";
    MySqlConnection connectDatabase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
    MySqlCommand commandDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, connectDatabase);
    MySqlDataReader myReader;

    try
    {
        connectDatabase.Open();
        myReader = commandDataBase.ExecuteReader();

        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            string sName = myReader.GetString("drinks_Name");
            listBox1.Items.Add(sName);
        }                
        {                    
            decimal MMPrice = myReader.GetDecimal("drinks_MPrice");
            decimal MLPrice = myReader.GetDecimal("drinks_LPrice");

            if (MediumButton.Checked == true )
            {
                 textBox1.Text = MMPrice.ToString();

            }
            else if (largeButton.Checked == true)
            {
                textBox1.Text = MLPrice.ToString();
            }         
        }*/       
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);                
    }          
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `CheckedChanged` event of radiobutton:

```
radioButton.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(radioButton_CheckedChanged);
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //your code to show price
    }
```

Comment: the CheckedChanged event need put at where？

Comment: The first line `radioButton.CheckedChanged += new....` should be in the constructor of your `form` class. The method `radioButton1_CheckedChanged` will be in the `form` like you create other methods.

Answer (score 0):

You placed your radio button handling inside the button click event, so you would have to click the *button* it in order to trigger everything inside the `_Click` method. Instead, create separate methods for the radio buttons *outside* of the `signatureMilkTeaButton_Click` event:

```
private void MediumButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShowPrice();
}

private void LargeButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShowPrice();  
}

private void ShowPrice()
{
     //...your database commands...

     if (MediumButton.Checked)
         textBox1.Text = "price1";

     else if (LargeButton.Checked)
         textBox1.Text = "price2";
}
```

Comment: connnectDatabase.Open();
            myReader = commandDataBase.ExecuteReader();

            decimal MMPrice = myReader.GetDecimal("drinks_MPrice");
            decimal MLPrice = myReader.GetDecimal("drinks_LPrice");

            if (MediumButton.Checked)
                priceTextBox.Text = MMPrice.ToString();

            else if (largeButton.Checked)
                priceTextBox.Text = MLPrice.ToString();
        }

it does not work

Comment: What happens when you add `largeButton.CheckedChanged += LargeButton_CheckChanged` and `MediumButtonButton.CheckedChanged += MediumButton_CheckChanged` after `InitializeComponent()` in your form's constructor?